# Full-text search with Stopwords in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, stop-words

I am using Full-Text search in MySQL. But when search it with Stopword result is empty.

What I want is operation like what we use with LIKE. Mean that, it do with all word. After I used Full-Text search, I think that it more powerful than LIKE, it can use with index FULLTEXT, with multiple field.

But, when search criteria in AGAINST is in list of Stopwords the result is EMPTY.

How can I use Full-Text search in MySQL that filter although word in Stopword?
Or
Others way that I can use with search algorithm?

Comment: I really need solution but still have no answers on my question...

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to mess with the [ft_stopword_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) system variable. Notice in particular:

> Setting this variable to the empty string ('') disables stopword filtering

Unfortunately, this setting cannot be changed on the fly, mostly because fulltext indexes must be rebuilt after changing it.

Comment: so it still have no solution?

Comment: @KH-DP Yes, this is a solution, despite the drawbacks.

Comment: You could disable stopword filtering, and when you want stopword filtering on, filter out all stopwords before-hand in whatever language you're using when connecting to your MySQL server, if you are.